# IOError error message in IPython notebook when using StarCluster

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel, starcluster

I am running a small StarCluster and using it to run an IPython Notebook. Every time I have an error in the code I'm writing in the notebook, I get the following error message added onto the end of the notebook's output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 872, in emit
    stream.write(fs % msg)
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Logged from file ipkernel.py, line 427
```

Other than that, it seems to be running OK, but I don't know why that might be happening / how I can find out more about why it's doing that

Comment: I am seeing the same error, but it doesn't seem to be affecting anything. I'd like to understand the source as well...